# Define Pin RX, TX Without SoftwareSerial Arduino

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm

Hi I did 2 diferent codes, then after verifying that they work i try to combine them and I got a problem. I used GSM.h to controle my GSM module, and to controle the GPS I used the SoftwareSerial.h.

I tryed to combine these to codes and this 2 libraries conflit with each other.

Can some one help me?

This is my code

```
//GSM
#include <GSM.h>
#define PINNUMBER "3805"
GSM gsmAccess; // include a 'true' parameter for debug enabled
GSM_SMS sms;
//N de telefone de envio
char remoteNumber[20]= "914181875";  
//Conteudo do SMS
char txtMsg[200]="Tester";
int val = 0;
//GPS
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>
TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(4, 3);

static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);

int button = 7; 

void setup()
{
  // initialize serial communications
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("SMS Messages Sender");

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while(notConnected)
  {
    if(gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY)
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("GSM initialized");
}

void loop()
{
val = digitalRead(button);
if (val == HIGH){
  sendSMS();
  }
}

void sendSMS(){

  Serial.print("Message to mobile number: ");
  Serial.println(remoteNumber);

  // sms text
  Serial.println("SENDING");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Message:");
  Serial.println(txtMsg);

  // send the message
  sms.beginSMS(remoteNumber);
  sms.print(txtMsg);
  sms.endSMS(); 
  Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");  
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to be more explicit about what your problem is, what errors you are getting, what you expect to get, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the AltSoftSerial library instead of SoftwareSerial:

https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/AltSoftSerial

The disadvantage of this library is it requires you to use specific pins for serial communication with your GPS hardware, which are different from the pins you're currently using:

```
// AltSoftSerial always uses these pins:
//
// Board          Transmit  Receive   PWM Unusable
// -----          --------  -------   ------------
// Teensy 3.0 & 3.1  21        20         22
// Teensy 2.0         9        10       (none)
// Teensy++ 2.0      25         4       26, 27
// Arduino Uno        9         8         10
// Arduino Leonardo   5        13       (none)
// Arduino Mega      46        48       44, 45
// Wiring-S           5         6          4
// Sanguino          13        14         12
```

I don't have the hardware to test but the following code does compile:

```
//GSM
#include <GSM.h>
#define PINNUMBER "3805"
GSM gsmAccess; // include a 'true' parameter for debug enabled
GSM_SMS sms;
//N de telefone de envio
char remoteNumber[20]= "914181875";  
//Conteudo do SMS
char txtMsg[200]="Tester";
int val = 0;
//GPS
#include <AltSoftSerial.h>
AltSoftSerial ss;
#include <TinyGPS.h>
TinyGPS gps;

static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);

int button = 7; 

void setup()
{
  // initialize serial communications
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("SMS Messages Sender");

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while(notConnected)
  {
    if(gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY)
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("GSM initialized");
}

void loop()
{
val = digitalRead(button);
if (val == HIGH){
  sendSMS();
  }
}

void sendSMS(){

  Serial.print("Message to mobile number: ");
  Serial.println(remoteNumber);

  // sms text
  Serial.println("SENDING");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Message:");
  Serial.println(txtMsg);

  // send the message
  sms.beginSMS(remoteNumber);
  sms.print(txtMsg);
  sms.endSMS(); 
  Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");  
}
```

Comment: Thx for your help,  yes it does compile but the hardware does start the ports conflict between them. How do i stop that?